# How to make the browser load the whole element at start?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Currently, if I scroll down on my website parts of my image take time to load kind of ruining the immersion.

How can I make the browser pre-load (and not unload) the whole image or a specific part of the image when the page is open?

I know this is probably a performance hit but I'll account for that.

[image: Image takes time to load after scroll instead of being pre-loaded]
*Image takes time to load after scroll instead of being pre-loaded*

Comment: You can add `load` listeners to all your images, and then only display the whole page once ALL images are loaded. Until that time you display a loading bar. For example `let img = new Image()` `img.src = "bla.png"` and then `img.addEventListener("load", ...)`

Comment: According to your tags: it's a SVG? Progressively rendered images usually indicate, the file is massive (due to embedded images, too many objects) or very rendering expensive (e.g caused by filters). So it might be necessary to optimize the image itself. Can you share an example?

Comment: @Kokodoko that's a great solution, write it down as an answer.

Comment: @herrstrietzel It's an .svg image with a lot of elements, would converting it to a .webp be faster? Would that impact the quality of the image then? Here's the image itself: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16P14LrgON24U2yrjv7CAJ0DEZTYtsKeV/view?usp=sharing (just one fat blob for the whole page except animated elements).

Comment: I see ... Your svg is actually quite demanding for the rendering engine (due to many objects, gradients, transformations etc.). Using a raster image might put less load on the renderer. Besides you could shrink down the filesize using an optimizer like [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) (be careful - the defaults are very aggressive! You'll most certainly need many shots to find the best settings).

Comment: Honestly, I think you should split your background image or separate background from content sections by removing the quite heavy svg text paths. More HTML/CSS work admittedly – but search engines won't  like these svg headings (e.g design, audio etc.) if they are paths and not readable text.

Comment: @herrstrietzel I'll try to optimize the image thanks! I've also been thinking about making text separate, although the website isn't meant to be SEO but I'll probably do that anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kokodoko's solution (written in the comments) of a adding a loading screen is definetely the best solution to my problem especially considering that I can't simply optimize the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rel=preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) to preload content like images.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preload" href="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600"
    as="image" crossorigin />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Image</h1>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600">
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Disable lazy loading with PHP;

```php
add_filter( 'wp_lazy_loading_enabled', '__return_false' );
```